# Ctrl + Page Down && Ctrl + Page Up

Tags: apt, keyboard, shortcuts

I use a MacBook pro and am using Linux Mint. I know this is an Ubuntu forum but Mint is built on top of Ubuntu so I am trying here.

The Macbook Pro doesn't have a Page Down or Page Up button. Applications such as Epiphany and Terminal use these buttons to switch between tabs. Ubuntu and Mint both use APT so I assume all applications are the same if not extremely similar. You cannot re-key-bind the terminal nor Epiphany. So I tried the Keyboard settings app and Keyboard Layout app to see if I could change the keys. This proved futile.

What I want is either to rebind the keys in Epiphany and the Terminal, or bind <kbd>Page up</kbd> and <kbd>Page down</kbd> to something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use a macbook air and the fn+up and fn+down keys provide page up and page down functionality.

Alternatively, you can map additional keys to the page up and down functions, i.e. the right command and alt/option keys (honestly, how often do you use them?)  Some info on this can be found here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

The short version is to use the xev program to determine what the key codes you want to change are, and create a program (say, ~/.Xmodmap) with information that remaps the key.  I use this to swap my capslock and delete keys using:

```
keycode 0x16 = Delete 
keycode 0x42 = Backspace
```

Then add the command "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" to either your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc files, and then run the command xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap from terminal, and your changes should take effect.

Answer (score 3):

You can press Ctrl + fn + up/down

Answer (score 1):

I assume this same process will work for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> as it did with <kbd>Alt</kbd> for me. Just be careful when testing the keys you assign using `xbindkeys-config`.

I read this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KeyboardShortcuts which helped me figure out the following. While the *xautomation* package that includes the `xte` tool might be used instead of `xvkbd` to emit the key codes I used `xvkbd` to do the same thing.

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys xbindkeys-config xvkbd

xbindkeys --defaults > /home/your-user-name/.xbindkeysrc
```

For some reason this added a binding for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> that I had to comment out. While perhaps a useful default example I need<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to find inside of web pages.

After figuring out the "keysims" of **Prior** for <kbd>*PgUp*</kbd> and **Next** for <kbd>*PgDown*</kbd> this wasn't too tough. Running and using `xbindkeys-config` resulted in the following entries in .xbindkeysrc for me.

```
#alt-up
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Prior]""
    m:0x18 + c:111
    Alt+Mod2 + Up

#alt-down
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Next]""
    m:0x18 + c:116
    Alt+Mod2 + Down
```

when using Ubuntu 12.04 precise pangolin after creating the .xbindkeysrc file it was detected and the `xbindkeys` program was run automatically on my next login.

So this should do what you want.

```
#ctrl-up
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Prior]""
    m:0x14 + c:111
    Ctrl+Mod2 + Up

#ctrl-down
"xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\[Next]""
    m:0x14 + c:116
    Ctrl+Mod2 + Down
```

Comment: Thanks for the formatting edits. The answer reads better now.